# Перегрузка оператора для a=a

Tags: c++

Посмотрел тут [лекцию](http://compscicenter.ru/program/lecture/4971). Описывается создание класса для массива. В частности речь зашла о переопределении оператора присваивания и его работа для случая a=a; (тайминг 1:02:40).

```
Array& Array::operator=(MyArray &a){
  mySize = a.mySize;
  delete [] myData;
  myData = new int[mySize];
  for(int i=0;i<mySize;i++){
    myData[i] = a.myData[i];
  }
  return *this;
}
```

ну и где-то идет:

```
Array a(10);
a.set(0,1000);//a[0]==1000;
a=a;
//a[0]==?
```

И декларируется, что в этом случае после освобождения памяти через delete по старому указателю может оказаться уже мусор и дальше будет идти копирование этого мусора.

Вопрос: куда будет ссылаться `a.myData` после `myData = new int[mySize]`?

У меня есть ощущение, что на новую область, а не на старую, и мусор (в виде нулей, например) там будет всегда, а не так что после удаления "другая часть нашей программы может начать использовать эту область" и потому там будет мусор, который мы потом скопируем.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Этот код для вызова `a = a` эквивалентен следующему коду:

  ```
    mySize = this->ySize;
    delete [] myData;
    myData = new int[mySize];
    for(int i=0;i<mySize;i++){
      myData[i] = this->myData[i];
    }
  ```
- В данном случае не происходит утечек памяти и не остается висящих указателей, однако, есть `undefined behavior` в строчке, где происходит копирование данных *(чтение данных из только что выделенного блока памяти - это `undefined behavior`).*
- Отвечая конкретно на ваш вопрос - `a.myData` и `myData` в скоупе `operator=` при вызове `a=a` эквивалентны, то есть всегда ссылаются на один и тот же участок памяти.

Comment: А как обойти проблему? Сравнить this и если они одинаковые, то сразу на выход?

Comment: @gecube Обычно, да.

Comment: @AlexeyM, а какие еще варианты?

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, ну то есть лектор слегка запутал студентов. Студенты проглотили.  Спасибо за ответ.
@gecube, есть еще неоптимальный вариант передавать параметр не по ссылке, а по значению, тогда будет создана копия a, с учетом того что описан конструтор копирования.